# check if any values in 2 arrays are equal

Tags: arrays, numpy, comparison, equality

I'd like to check if  any element (regardless of its position) of an array can be found in a second array.

For example

1st array:   `array([1,4,7,5,3])`

2nd array:   `array([5,2,9,0,6])`

Then I would want to find out, that `5` occurs in both arrays.

I guess that

```py
array1 == array2
```

is not the right operation to check for this.

how can I test, if there are the same 2 elements in 2 arrays?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use [**`np.isin(...)`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) here to check if the value of an array is in another array, and then check with [**`.any()`** [numpy-doc]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) if that is the case for at least one such item:

```
>>> np.isin(array1, array2).any()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try getting intersection of 2 arrays:

```py
list(set(arr_1) & set(arr_2))
```

or alternatively:

```py
list(set(arr_1).intersection(set(arr_2)))
```

To count overlapping elements - just get length of the intersection:

```py
len(list(set(arr_1) & set(arr_2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is to use `numpy.add.outer` and check if there are zeros in the resulting array:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 4)
b = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 4)

print(a, b)

print(numpy.add.outer(a, -b))
has_dups = numpy.any(numpy.add.outer(a, -b) == 0)
print(has_dups)
```